# How to find the theme object id in WebSpherePortal server?

Tags: websphere-6.1

Am trying to export some portal pages with the theme.In the out put xml file am getting my local theme reference id.So when i tried to import the generated xml file i have to mention the local theme object id as themeref.Any one tell me how to find the theme object id in WebSpherePortal server 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XMLAccess we can find the theme object id in WebSphere Portal Server.After running the Export.xml in the out put file the we can find the object id associate with in the tag.